# Can the newsletter be targetted towards favorite tags?

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

Has there has been consideration of customizing the newsletter based on a user's "Favorite Tags"?  I like getting the newsletter and discovering some new and interesting things. I'm not adverse to seeing items for areas I never really deal with.  But it would be really nice to have a section somewhat related or filtered down to my own interests.

Comment: There's a newsletter?

Comment: **Please Yes**! Also see these Meta posts: [How about an interesting newsletter?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247298) | [Weekly newsletters are not customizable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110834)

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? Can I get a newsletter for my specific tags only?