# Weekly newsletter section "Can you answer these?" - Make questions relevant to me

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

I get the weekly newsletter and my answer to the section titled "Can you answer these?" is inevitable always "No" because the question are never relevant to my interests/expertise. The tags on the questions listed just about never include my favorited tags. So I usually have no knowledge of the answer nor do I have an interest in finding the answer. (insert confused Gandalf meme here)

I would suggest making the questions line up with favorite tags. And even better, line up with my next badge goal.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288234/can-the-newsletter-be-targetted-towards-favorite-tags?rq=1

Comment: Yes related to that feature request. This is a little different because that request is for the entire newsletter whereas this request is only for the section: "Can you answer these?"

Comment: That isn't really the way the world works.  Certainly not the newsletter, it is not personalized.  If a good question (assumed) doesn't get answer from the subject experts then it usually takes somebody that *doesn't* use the subject area every day to find the outlier answer.  Rumor has it that Einstein wasn't good at math.

Comment: If the spirit of this section is to find the diamond in the rough which can find the answer to these unanswered and difficult questions, then I think the title needs a revision. So everyone gets the same newsletter?  Frankly, that's disappointing.  And I don't think I agree with your statement. If no one has given an acceptable answer on these questions, I would first lean toward a deeper subject matter expert that hasn't discovered the question yet than the community at large.  By the way, Einstein had mastered differential and integral calculus before he was fifteen.